# File Download Using Ajax and iframe

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iframe, razor

I have read about doing a file download using Ajax and iframes.
Can anybody give me a step by step explanation of how to do this or know of any tutorials seeing as we are already using ajax on this project this seems like the best way to do this.

EDIT:

Okay this is my view code:

```
<div class="buttons">
<input type="button" value="Download File" class="button" id="downloadfile">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $('#downloadfile').click(function (e) {
        $('#downloadIframe').attr('src', '@Url.Action("DownloadFile","Invoice")' + '/Report/Invoices');
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
public FileResult DownloadFile(int id)
    {

        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Invoices/" + Table.First(x => x.ID == id).ID + ".pdf"));
        string fileName = Table.First(x => x.ID == id).ID.ToString();
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, fileName);
    }

    public ActionResult Download(int id)
    {
        return AjaxResponse("Download", null);
    }
```

I have a `Jquery` context menu that I use to click on a row in a `JQGrid` and then open the view `Download` and then in the view I click the button and it should execute the `script` in the view and return `DownloadFile` `FileResult` in the controller but nothing happens when I click the button.

The folder where the reports are: `~/Reports/Invoices`

Comment: `'@Url.Action("DownloadFile","Invoice")' + '/Report/Invoices'`, instead of `'/Report/Invoices'` you need to give a valid file ID. I think that is the only change you need to download the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about iframes, but my way of downloading files through ajax is just a simple writing to the response stream.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(VaryByCustom="id")]
    public void DownloadFile(int id)
    {
        var path = GetFilePath(id);
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=xxx");
        Response.WriteFile(path);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: What is the reference for `path` & `GetFilePath`?

Comment: It's just an example. Simply set path as a name with path to the file you want to be downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the solution -

Say you have a controller of this way -

```
public class SubmitController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Download(string id)
    {
        string filename = String.Format("{0}.pdf", id);
        return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Content/") + filename), "application/octet-stream", filename);
    }
}
```

Where Index action is going to return the following view -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function () {
        $('#downloadfile').click(function (e) {
            $('#downloadIframe').attr('src', '@Url.Action("Download","Submit")' + '/Report');
        });
    });

</script>

<input type="button" value="Download file" id="downloadfile"/>
<iframe id="downloadIframe"></iframe>
```

Once you click on the button - "Download File", you will get the iframe loaded with the URL in which we specify download Report.pdf (this can be dynamic as per your need).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot trigger the download using the ajax. but you can file download by setting the URL to the `window.location`

In you c# return the file

```
byte[] bytes = .... insert your bytes in the array
return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "somefilename.exe");
```

and In the js

```
window.location="download.action?para1=value1...."
```

Otherwise you can use the [jquery.FileDownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload) plugin which handles the download.

**Edit**

Try

```
window.location=" @string.Format("{0}{1}{2}","~/Reports/Invoices/",ViewBag.ID,".pdf") ";
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to implement `window.location="download.action?para1=value1...."`

Comment: I have an IFrame: `<iframe id="invFrame" src="~/Reports/Invoices/@(ViewBag.ID).pdf?ts=@(DateTime.Now.Ticks)" style="display: none"></iframe>` on load of the view I want to download `"~/Reports/Invoices/@(ViewBag.ID).pdf`

Comment: Thank you for the example but it displays the pdf in the current windows. How can I set the target that it does not replace the the current window but brings up the save file dialog

Comment: try setting it to `window.location.href = "your url"`. it might trigger the download window. and also set the `Content-Disposition: attachment' in the response from the server.